# grunt-usemin integration for custom file types

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin, grunt-wiredep

I have a question about theme deployment.

**bower** and **wiredep** modules works quite nicely, I add a lot of content this way! however, now I have to combine these files such as **bundle.js**, **bundle.css** etc... grunt-usemin module works very well for this purpose, but I could not find an integration for **Drupal theme info file** ( *see:* https://www.drupal.org/node/171205 ) Below you can see a sample file:

#### theme_name.info :

```config
name = Theme
description = Tableless, recolorable, multi-column, fluid width theme (default).
version = 1.0
core = 7.x

;bower:css
stylesheets[all][] = src/components/module1/style1.css
stylesheets[all][] = src/components/module2/style2.css
;endbower

;bower:js
scripts[] = src/components/module/dist/vendor.js
scripts[] = src/components/module2/dist/script.js
;endbower
```

#### grunt wiredep task :

```js
wiredep: {
  task: {
    src: ['theme_name.info'],
    options: {
        fileTypes: {
            info: {
              block: /(([ \t]*);\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(;\s*endbower)/gi,
              detect: {
                js: /scripts\[\] = \s(.+js)/gi,
                css: /stylesheets\[all\]\[\] = \s(.+css)/gi
              },
              replace: {
                js: 'scripts[] = {{filePath}}',
                css: 'stylesheets[all][] = {{filePath}}'
              }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Well, I need **grunt-usemin** task for custom info file... Waiting for your help in this regard.

Thank you.